# Changing log mode

Tags: python

I have logging set up. However, it is only printing things that are `INFO` and above. How would I modify this to print `DEBUG` and above?

Here is the code I currently have:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('avails')
log.debug('Does not show in print to console')
log.info('Show in print to console')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after "import logging", add:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

There are many other ways, but that is probably the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

here is your answer in python document.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel